# Can I use GCP Client API in Airflow tasks directly?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Airflow(GCP Composer) now.

I know it has GCS hook and I can download some GCS files.

But I'd like to read a file partially.

Can I use this python logic with PythonOperator in DAG?

```
from google.cloud import storage

def my_func():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket("mybucket")
    blob = bucket.get_blob("myfile")
    data = blob.download_as_bytes(end=100)
    return data
```

In Airflow task, is direct Client API call which is not using hooks forbidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but a more Airflowy to handle missing functionality in the hook is to extend the hook:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook
class MyGCSHook(GCSHook):

    def download_bytes(
        self,
        bucket_name: str,
        object_name: str,
        end:str,
    ) -> bytes:
        client = self.get_conn()
        bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_name=object_name)
        return blob.download_as_bytes(end=end)
```

Then you can use the hook function in PythonOperator or in a custom operator.

To note that `GCSHook` has [download](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f23769f6970d9dce34c55c0e0132db4532d57cd3/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs.py#L267) function as you mention.
What you may have missed is that if you don't provide filename it will download as bytes (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f23769f6970d9dce34c55c0e0132db4532d57cd3/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs.py#L309-L314)). It doesn't allow to configure the `end` parameter as you expect but this should be an easy fix to PR for Airflow if you are looking to contributing to Airflow open source.